# Не могу принять post запрос из requests python в express.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, requests, express

Есть некий клиент, который отправляет POST-запрос на сервер:

```
response = requests.post('http://localhost:7777/state/makeApplication', data={'department': 'not defined','referrer': 'Abubakr Shomirsaidov','type': 'not defined','time': '20.05.2022'})
```

И сервер, который получает пустой `body`:

```
app.use(express.json())
app.post('state/makeApplication', (req,res) => {console.log(req.body)})
```

Выводится `{ }`. То есть ничего.

Помогите, пожалуйста, это срочно!

Comment: По умолчанию запрос отправляется в виде `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` так что вам нужен не `express.json`,  а [`express.urlencoded`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded)